# JavaScript and Java RPC-style communication

Tags: java, javascript, extjs

I want some lightweight RPC-like communication mechanism between java and javascript. I like [Ext Direct](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/extdirect)
and there are some pretty easy to use java implementations, but I don't want to take whole ext-js to my project. So, I'm looking for some specific java and JS lib to simplify client-server communication.

Comment: Are you lloking for GWT ?

Comment: No.I need only a communication tool. For example, I have some Java-class with some public methods. And the methods accept some params and return some POJOs. I mark the methods with special annotation, and now I can access them from the javascript: MyJavaAction.getCurrentState(...) and this will invoke appropriate java method and transfer the result back to the JavaScript.